# Add Husky(Git Hooks) into Azure DevOps Project

Tags: github, azure-devops, githooks, azure-repos, git-husky

My repository is on AzureDevops, and I cloned it by the button: "Clone in VS Code". The repository was cloned correctly. I have the files from package.json, .gitignore, etc...

But I don't have a .git folder. And I would like to install some tool to standardize code commits. I try to install husky 7 but it doesn't find the .git folder which doesn't really exist.

Is there any way to use git hooks for the repository within Azure Devops?

Is there any other tool for standardizing commits that works in an Azure Devops repository?

When i try to install husky, i get that error: .git can't be found (see https://git.io/Jc3F9)

```
husky -v = ^7.0.0,
npm -v = 6.14.12
```